# Logarithmic question: $n^{1/\lg n}=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How is:

$$n^{\Large\frac 1{\lg n}} = 2\ ? $$

I don't understand this is their any formula to calculate this

what is the difference between $\lg n$ & $\log n$? Is logarithm base $2$ ?

Comment: See my editing, is this correct?

Comment: No, $\ln$ means the basis is $e$.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey yaa its cool Thanks a lot

Comment: We learned in school: $lg$ is the logarithm with basis $10$; $ln$ ("natural logarithm") with basis $e$ and $log$ has an arbitrary basis ($\neq 0$) and is written as $log_n$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Matthias very late answer: that's correct, but sometimes $\operatorname{lg}$ can also mean other bases like $2$ in this question, and sometimes (almost always in undergraduate/graduate textbooks) $\log$ is assumed to mean $\log_e$. $\operatorname{lg}$ and $\operatorname{ln}$ is almost never used beyond high school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here $\lg$ means $\lg 2$, so $n^{\frac{1}{\lg_2 n}}=n^{\lg_n 2}=2$.

Answer (score 3):

In your question, $\lg$ is base 2. By applying $\lg$ to your equation, you get
$\lg( n^{1/\lg n} ) = \lg 2.$
Using the law $b \lg a = \lg(a^b)$, we find
$1 = \lg 2$
which is true, since $\lg$ has base 2.

Comment: @Winther: oops :)

Comment: I never know that $\lg$ is $\log$ base $2$. +1 for the info.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: $\log$ conventions are sometimes confusing. In Russia $\log_a$ is used only with a specified base, there is no just $\log$. Also, $\ln x := \log_{\mathrm e}x$, $\lg x := \log_{10} x$. I never heard of $\log_2$ having a special notation in Russian, but Wikipedia suggests it is $\mathrm{lb}\, x$. I can imagine, in other countries conventions are different.

Comment: @Ilya Here in my country, Indonesia, $\log$ means logarithm base $10$ and $\ln$ means logarithm base $e$. As far as I know, there is no such thing as $\lg$ or $\text{lb}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $ \lg n $ is short for $ \log_{2} n $ (the logarithm base 2 of a number $ n $). $ \lg n $ is also referred to as the **binary** logarithm. You can read more about the binary logarithm on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm

For now, though, $$n^{\Large\frac 1{\lg n}} $$ $$ = n^{\Large\frac 1{\log_{2} n}}$$ $$= n^{\Large\frac {\log_{2} 2}{\log_{2} n}} $$ $$ = n^{\log_{n} 2} $$ $$= 2 $$